# Calculate the minimum difference among the three column and give the corresponding column name in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have data as follows,

```
data

required_value          Value1          Value2        Value3
     0.5                  .1              0.3           0.4
     1.0                   1              0.7           0.2
     1.5                  .37             0.3           0.7
     2.0                  1.25            0.9           1.9
```

I want to find which of the three columns(Value1, Value2, Value3) are closest to the required value and create a new column and have the columnname of the column. My sample output is,

data

```
required_value          Value1          Value2        Value3       output
     0.5                  .1              0.3           0.4        Value3
     1.0                   1              0.7           0.2        Value1
     1.5                  .37             0.3           0.7        Value3
     2.0                  1.25            0.9           1.9        Value3
```

I am able to find the closet value in this. But not able to get the corresponding column name. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: how did you find the closest value? that bit of code seems to be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this answer to what looks like a homework assignment against my better judgement.

```
read.table(text="required_value          Value1          Value2        Value3
     0.5                  .1              0.3           0.4
     1.0                   1              0.7           0.2
     1.5                  .37             0.3           0.7
     2.0                  1.25            0.9           1.9", header=TRUE) -> df


df$output <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  names(x)[which.min(abs(x[2:4] - x[1]))+1]
})

##   required_value Value1 Value2 Value3 output
## 1            0.5   0.10    0.3    0.4 Value3
## 2            1.0   1.00    0.7    0.2 Value1
## 3            1.5   0.37    0.3    0.7 Value3
## 4            2.0   1.25    0.9    1.9 Value3
```

UPDATE:

I knew `sweep()` had alot of code cruft in it but, wow:

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 apply   83.281  103.156  117.414  113.479  126.790  256.216   100
 sweep 1116.052 1194.766 1292.346 1218.801 1301.724 2309.745   100
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can break this down to a `?max.col` operation, after sweeping out the differences between the first column and the remaining columns:

```
names(df[-1])[max.col(-abs(sweep(df[-1], 1, df$required_value)),"first")]
#[1] "Value3" "Value1" "Value3" "Value3"
```

To address @hrbrmstr 's benchmarks that show this is slower. Yes, it will be slower when the data is small as the overhead of the functions will take a few microseconds more. This code should however scale so that while you lose out by fractions of a second on small data, it will run much faster as the size ramps up. Example timings in **seconds**:

```
-sweep/max.col
           user  system elapsed
10k        0.00    0.00    0.00
100k       0.17    0.01    0.19
1M         1.36    0.12    1.49 
5M         3.99    0.59    4.58 

-apply
           user  system elapsed 
10k        0.05    0.00    0.05
100k       0.56    0.00    0.57
1M         7.33    0.08    7.41
5M        41.36    0.13   41.52
```

Comment: wow, i did not expect the benchmarks to be that much different but they were.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - try it with something bigger than 4 rows - `max.col/sweep` is faster when the data gets bigger - try 100K or 1M rows. For 1M sweep is 1.5 secs vs. 7.4secs for apply. 1000microseconds is 0.001 seconds and probably not worth sweating about if you only have small data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also transform the data from wide to long format then filter out the variable that has the minimum difference from the required value:

```
library(data.table)
data$id <- seq_len(nrow(data))   # create an id variable for group by operation
longData <- melt(data, id.vars = c("id", "required_value"))   # transform to long format
data[longData[, .(variable[which.min(abs(value - required_value))]) ,.(id)], on = "id"]

   required_value Value1 Value2 Value3 id     V1
1:            0.5   0.10    0.3    0.4  1 Value3
2:            1.0   1.00    0.7    0.2  2 Value1
3:            1.5   0.37    0.3    0.7  3 Value3
4:            2.0   1.25    0.9    1.9  4 Value3
```